# Is the source for tefillin Raavad in his hassagot to MT, hilkhot tefillin 3:5?

Tags: tefilin

I am looking for earlier mekorot on tefillin according to Raavad (following the order of שמע, והי׳ אם, והי׳ כי, קדש, or the reverse of Rabbeinu Tam). Is this comment (to MT hilkhot tefillin 3:5) the primary source? If anyone can point me to discussion of Rishonim on tefillin Raavad, also appreciated.

Comment: Rabbeinu Tam & Ra'avad are two different variations of tefillin. See Shu't of Menachem Azaryah of Fano (Acharon) for details. This link to the other Acharon, the Megaleh Amukot, may give you some leads to run down. https://www.sefaria.org/Megaleh_Amukot.172?vhe=Megaleh_Amukot,_based_on_Krakow,_1637_edition&lang=bi

Comment: Thank you, yes, I am aware of the differences and these two sources, but I should give them a close read, maybe they'll point me earlier.